# Javascript: Pushing items to an Array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm basically trying to loop through an array to check if an item already exists:

> If the the item exists, **remove** it
>
> If the item does not exist, **push** it to the array

However my code only allows me to add **one** item only. It ignores every other value I'm trying to add.

```
var inclfls = []; //new empty array
function addfile(val) {
 if (inclfls.length != 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < inclfls.length; i++) {
            if (inclfls[i] == val) {
                a.style.background = "#999";
                inclfls.splice(i, 1); //remove it
            }
            else {
                a.style.background = "#2ECC71";
                inclfls.push(val); //push it
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        a.style.background = "#2ECC71";
        inclfls.push(val);
    }

    alert(inclfls.length);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: dont modify anything until you check the whole array. on the first non-match, you add it in, and then it's in the array. in fact, you add it for evey non match?

Comment: *"If the the item exists, **remove** it"* That seems like a **very** odd thing for a function called `addfile` to do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Don't judge :D Something I need to do right now mate

Comment: Oh mate I wasn;t being rude.. :O @T.J.Crowder .dandavis sorry about that

Comment: Noted :) Removed comment. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: no, it looked rude only after i deleted my first comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with array methods, its much simpler:

```
function addfile(val) {
  var index=inclfls.indexOf(val);
  if(index===-1){ 
   inclfls.push(val); 
   a.style.background = "#999";
  }else{ 
    inclfls.splice(index,1);
    a.style.background = "#2ECC71";
 }
}
```

Comment: Note that `indexOf` uses `===` comparisons. The OP's using `==`. Probably fine to use `===`, but worth noting.

Comment: Perfect!! Simple and clean code. Thanks dandavis and @T.J.Crowder. I will accept this in 3 mins

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: good point. we can't tell the item type from the OP, but yeah, it probably doesn't matter, or is actually better, since OP's code would remove `"1"` and `[1]`  from `[1,2,3]`